# Could Jar Jar Binks live long enough to appear in the next Star Wars trilogy?

Tags: star-wars, jar-jar-binks

What is the lifespan of a Gungan, how old was Jar Jar in the Episode I–III trilogy, and when does the VII–IX trilogy take place in reference to the I–III trilogy?

Comment: About 65 Galactic years.

Comment: If I google "lifespan of a Gungan" the first hit says 65 galactic years. So you raised this question here to avoid google finding out that you are interested in star wars?

Comment: This isn't exactly opinion based.

Comment: @GorchestopherH I agree, but I added some specificity to appease the Moderator.  Also, Einer, I don't think you quite got the point of the question, but thanks for the input!

Comment: Unfortunately, Movie Canon trumps all other canon, so if they decide to bring Jar-Jar back (unlikely), he's coming back whether we like it or not.

Comment: I saw The real first Star Wars on the big screen, the weekend it came out. Those who were fans and looked forward to the second trilogy were unanimous that Jar-jar was an awful character. I doubt there will be another Gungan in the next trilogy.

Comment: @Zibbobz only for past stuff. [All new materials published from now on are 100% canon.](http://starwars.com/news/the-legendary-star-wars-expanded-universe-turns-a-new-page.html)

Comment: Hopefully the only Gungan in the next trilogy is JJ Abrams

Comment: Don't give them ideas...

Comment: @Einer: The [site](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gungan) you're probably referring to says "65 galactic *standard* years". It's an important distinction, since in real life a "[galactic year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_year)" is more than 200 million terrestrial years.

Comment: @KeithThompson That's odd, because a [standard Galactic Week](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/How_long_was_a_standard_galactic_week_in_the_Men_in_Black_movies) is only an hour.

Comment: Probably not but don't rule out Jar Jar junior

Comment: His son "Jar-Jar Binks, the second" can always be featured.

Comment: No, he was accidentally maliciously murdered by...someone

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Most sites quote the lifespan of a Gungan at ~65 years. The source for this figure seems to be the *Ultimate Alien Anthology*, which goes into slightly more detail about Gungan age and lifespan:

> **Age in Years:** Child 1–12; young adult 13–15; adult 16–35; middle age 36–54; old 55–64; venerable 65+.

According to his [Wookieepedia entry](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jar_Jar_Binks), Jar-Jar was born in 52 BBY. It references *Star Wars: Episode I Insider's Guide*, a game which discussed details of the expanded universe, but I haven't found a copy of the original entry in the game.

In March 2014, Disney and Lucasfilm announced [a timeline for the VII–IX trilogy](https://starwars.com/news/star-wars-episode-vii-set-to-roll-cameras-may-2014.html):

> It has also been confirmed that Star Wars: Episode VII is set **about 30 years after the events of *Star Wars:* Episode VI *Return of the Jedi***, and will star a trio of new young leads along with some very familiar faces.

Since *Return of the Jedi* is set in 4 ABY, this puts Episode VII around 34 ABY. This means Jar-Jar would have to be at around 86 at the start of the new trilogy. The ages above don't put a Gungan living to 86 outside the realms of possibility, but I would think it's fairly unlikely.

Comment: Fairly unlikely in Jar-Jar's case especially, because he was probably stoned as soon as he went back to Naboo after episode III.

Comment: @Xantec You mean in the sense that people threw stones at him? Just wanting to be clear.

Comment: @DJClayworth That was my original intention. Death by the other kind of stoning would seem too kindhearted.

Comment: Jar-Jar will have aged quite a bit and will in fact assume a Yoda-like role in the new trilogy.

Comment: After episode III he antagonised an Imperial officer that saw fit to have a"unique trophy" so he carbon froze poor Jar-Jar. Fast forward to episode 7. Kids are exploring some bombed out ruins and find Jar-Jar encased in carbon. They use him as a hoversled for the rest of the triology as a Means of transport!  REMEMBER!! i called it first!!

Comment: His son Jar-Jar Binks, the second can always be featured.

Comment: Jar-Jar does make a canon appearance post-ROTJ in the Aftermath: Empire's End novel. In that scene, he seems fairly spry, performing as a clown to refugees on Naboo. It's quite possible he could live on another 15-20 years

Answer (score 2):

1) Their life expectancy is 65 years (Wookieepedia)

2) Approximately 40 years passed between episode 1 and 6. The 7 is supposed to take place at least 20 to 40 years after the episode 6.
Jar Jar would need to be a maximum of 5 years old in the episode 1 to be still alive by then.

3) . Lucas said that only C-3PO and R2-D2 were the characters that would make it through the nine Star Wars films (Wikipédia)

So the answer is probably "no".

Comment: Regarding your third point, that doesn't mean he can't show up in one or two of the next three movies. Also, since Lucas no longer has complete control, his original intentions/visions are not necessarily still applicable.

Comment: @phantom42 Indeed, perhaps that is who Andy Serkis will be portraying.

Comment: 65 is presumably a life expectancy, not a maximum lifespan.  According to his Wookieepedia article, Jar Jar was born in 52 BBY (making him 20 as of episode 1) and Wookieepedia says episode 7 takes place in 34 ABY, so he'd need to be 86.  Assuming a similar distribution, the odds of a gungan living to that age would be similar to the odds of a human living to 110, i.e. definitely possible, but _really_ rare.

Comment: Might not even be rare, since life expectancy also factors in lifestyle risks.  Accidental death from animal attack is probably rare on the capital city of the empire, while there were big fish around his city IIRC on his homeworld.