# Is Jar Jar alive?

Tags: star-wars, jar-jar-binks

I know there are questions about Jar Jar’s age and relevance in the films already, but I was under the impression that when all the Jedi were killed between 3 and 4 that he had been murdered as well. Am I wrong? Or do we not know?

Comment: Order 66 was specifically targeting Jedi, which Jar Jar was not - so do you have anything in canon to indicate he might have been targeted?  Other than taste?

Comment: Related, not dupe: [Could Jar Jar Binks live long enough to appear in the next Star Wars trilogy?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55325/could-jar-jar-binks-live-long-enough-to-appear-in-the-next-star-wars-trilogy) and [Does Jar-Jar have some force ability?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11944/does-jar-jar-have-some-force-ability)

Comment: 'I was under the impression ... he had been murdered as well'. One can only hope...

Comment: Meesa isa alive!!!

Comment: I think we can all hope that it was slow and painful

Comment: @joshbirk `do you have anything in canon to indicate he might have been targeted?` `The Imperial Senate will no longer be of any concern to us. I've just received word that the Emperor has dissolved the council permanently`

Comment: @MrLore To me, that's more of an indication that he *wasn't* targeted for death. They dissolved the senate, but there's no mention that they were killed.

Comment: @phantom42 When evil guys use ambiguous words like "dissolve", I think it's not a leap to assume he means "acid" rather than "pink slip".

Comment: The Emperor was **so** evil...he kept Jar-Jar alive.

Comment: In the Star Wars fan fiction I wrote he was slowly tortured to death.

Comment: @MrLore I'm pretty certain the Emperor did not actually put the entire Senate to death.  If a troublemaker like Bail Organa survives to ANH, Jar Jar was probably pretty safe.  But props for the dissolution imagery...

Comment: @Oldcat: there’s a scary thought about what the second prequel could have been like. *Attack of the Clones... of Jar-Jar*.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Even Palpatine **isn't that** evil!

Comment: @Oldcat: Lucas might be.

Comment: If he's still alive I'll kill him myself. I swear it!

Comment: Is he alive?   No, he's CGI.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### In what was previously considered "C-Canon" (now "Legends"), Jar-Jar survived until at least 6.5 ABY.

He made an appearance in an expansion of the [Star Wars: Galactic Battlegrounds](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Galactic_Battlegrounds:_Clone_Campaigns) game.

From [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jar_Jar_Binks):

> Binks was alive and well in 6.5 ABY, and was present on Coruscant during its liberation from the Galactic Empire by troops of the New Republic. While he was never involved in this liberation, he was situated relatively close to some of the action.

Regarding whether or not not he can/will appear in Episodes 7-9...

The guidebook [Ultimate Alien Anthology](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Alien_Anthology) specifies that Gungans live an average of 65 standard galactic years.

According to [Star Wars: Episode 1 Insider's Guide](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_I_Insider%27s_Guide), Jar Jar was born in the year 52 BBY.

Statistically speaking, that leaves 9 years for Jar Jar to live (The Battle of Endor occurred in 4 ABY).  Since rumors state that the new trilogy will take place 20+ years after the Battle of Endor, it is *unlikely* that Jar Jar will have survived until the timeframe of the new movies.

<strike>With the recent Canon Purge, however, it is unknown what his current fate is, or what the average lifespan of a Gungan is.</strike>

### In Disney Canon, Jar-Jar survives until at least the timeframe between *Return of the Jedi* and *The Force Awakens*.

Jar Jar appears in the new Book *[Star Wars Aftermath: Empire's End](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aftermath:_Empire's_End)*.

[Mashable explains](http://mashable.com/2017/02/16/jar-jark-binks-back):

> The conclusion of a trilogy, mostly set between Return of the Jedi and The Force Awakens, Empire's End contains plenty of rewards for long-term fans. One of these is an interlude set on the planet of Naboo. A refugee boy named Mapo encounters a Gungan performing for kids on the streets, clowning around in a fountain twice a day while being studiously avoided by the grown-ups.
>
> "Meesa Jar Jar," says the clown when Mapo introduces himself. 
>   The clown distracts the orphan from his own sadness by popping his eyes and bulging his cheeks, but is hiding a sadness of his own.
>
> "Jar Jar makin some uh-oh mistakens," the Gungan says, explaining why he isn't wanted anywhere either. "Desa hisen Naboo tink I help the uh-oh Empire." He stares into the distance, suggesting he knows more than he's saying.

Comment: I answered as best I could as far as when Jar Jar was last seen alive. Whether he is "currently" alive or not really depends on when "now" is, as there is no "now" in the Star Wars Universe since the books/movies take place over thousands of years.

Comment: Yeah thats a very fair point. Well thanks for the input.

Comment: Who is or isn't in the new movies isn't up to Lucas anymore.

Comment: Watch for my cameo. Now that Lucas is out of the picture, @Tango and I are shoo-ins.

Comment: Honestly?  The image of an old, battle-hardened Jar-Jar with no speech impediment and decades of knowledge and expereience is the sort of thing that could completely make up for everything that happened in Episode 1.

Answer (score 1):

According to *Star Wars: Droid Tales*, the last we see of Jar Jar is he is floating in space past the Death Star II (see 2:52 in the below video):

Comment: For being non-canonical? (just a guess, I'm not one of the downvoters)

Comment: Video is no longer available - can you please update the link?

Comment: Video still dead.

Answer (score -1):

I think that Jar Jar would have survived for two reasons:

- **One** - because killing Jar Jar would result in a huge argument in the senate because people like Jar Jar - from the people of alderaan to the people of naboo -
- **Two** - also it is rumored in the 6<sup>th</sup> movie, near the end, that Jar Jar says "Mesa is alive". I for one have no proof of this but it is a possibility; though you would have to listen to the audio to see if it is true.

Comment: 1) Why is the assumption that he was "killed"? He could just as easily have just died of old age or natural causes. Of course, being Jar Jar, someone probably *wanted* to kill him.

Comment: 2) Yes, statistically speaking, he was young enough to be alive at the end of RotJ. In previous C Canon, he appears again at a later date.