# What happened to Jar Jar Binks when the Senate became "no more"?

Tags: star-wars, jar-jar-binks

In *Episode IV: A New Hope* when Commander Tagge is talking about the Rebellion gaining support in the senate Grand Moff Tarkin enters as says

> The Imperial Senate will no longer be of any concern to us. I've just received word that the Emperor has dissolved the council permanently. The last remnants of the Old Republic have been swept away.

This got me thinking, considering that Palpatine would've had anyone oppose him killed and Jar Jar didn't seem all that enthusiastic about allowing the Grand Army of the Republic which became the groundwork for the Imperial Army what happened to Jar Jar after the Senate became "no more"?

Comment: He went home to Naboo?

Comment: I sincerely hope he died.  Painfully.

Comment: Taken out behind the chemical sheds...

Comment: my [existing answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/63453/5184) explains that Jar Jar was still alive and on Coruscant at the time of RotJ in Legends Canon, but there was and is still no Disney Canon information.

Comment: Some theorise that he is a powerful Sith lord...

Answer (score 4):

Within the main canon, there are no further mentions of [Jar Jar Binks](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jar_Jar_Binks/Canon) after the events of Revenge of the Sith. The last time we see him is at Padmé's funeral on Naboo.

I think we can all hope that Tarkin was speaking literally and that Jar Jar was **actually dissolved.**

---

As to whether Palpatine would have allowed Jar Jar to survive after the creation of the Empire, [Ahmed Best](http://www.ew.com/article/2012/02/11/star-wars-deleted-scene-revenge-of-the-sith-jar-jar-binks) certainly seemed to think so;

> *“In Revenge of the Sith, there was a scene that was cut where I’m
>   walking down a long pathway with Ian McDiarmid before he is turned
>   into the Emperor,” Best explains. “And Palpatine kind of thanks Jar
>   Jar for putting him in power. It’s a really interesting scene, and it
>   shows the evolution of Jar Jar from this fun-loving kid’s character
>   into this manipulated politician. And it was an interesting arc for
>   the character that I thought could have been explored, because the
>   scene is really dark. But it just didn’t fit in the movie, which I
>   understand. But yeah, **George’s take on it is Jar Jar is now just a
>   politician.”***

Comment: You sure he didn't become Palpatine's other Sith apprentice?