# How old was Jar-Jar by Gungan standards?

Tags: star-wars, jar-jar-binks

With all the ragging on Jar Jar Binks for the ... less than wise way he is portrayed to behave, it dawned on me; he basically behaves in a very juvenile way, yet is judged by the fans as an adult.

How old was Jar Jar by Gungan standards? Is he (like Queen Amidala) a teenager equivalent of a Gungan or a fully-grown adult?

Comment: Some of the information about Gungan ages in one of my old answers (but I don't have a date for the prequels): http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/55334/3567

Comment: @alexwlchan EP1 was 32BBY.

Answer (score 6):

**Based on now Legends information from [The Ultimate Alien Anthology](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ultimate_Alien_Anthology), Jar Jar was considered an "adult" Gungan.**

- Jar Jar was born in 52 BBY
- Gungans have an average lifespan of [65 years](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/63453/5184)
- Episode 1 took place in 32 BBY, making Jar Jar 20 years old when we meet him.
- According to [*The Ultimate Alien Anthology*](http://roqoodepot.com/articles/ultimate-alien-anthology-lifespans/), ages 16-35 are considered "Adult".

Comment: that last bullet point sounds really weird by modern Western cultural standards :)

Comment: Oh I've sorry; you are 36.  You are too old to make resposible choices.  Bobby here is 16 and is our congressman.  He'll take care of you for the next 19 years.